# For Loop to print out 10 values by multiplying

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, printing, timer

I have been figuring out on finding the right loop to print out values, so I thought For loop would be easier to work with. I want to print out values 10 times along with timer results from starting at 1000 to 10000 or 1 to 10, whatever you call it. Here is the code:

```
cout << " N Value | Array Sort Time | Listed List Sort Time" << endl;
cout << "               (seconds)           (seconds) " << endl;
cout << endl;

for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{

    x = x*n;
    printf(" %d", n);
    int m = n; //copy N value for new integer to do 2nd while loop

    begin = clock();
    while(n != 0)
    {
        input = rand()%n;

        addArray(input, pArray, size);
        n--;

        if( input == -1)
        {
            break;   // end of list, don't add it to list
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("          %5.3f", time_spent);

    begin = clock();
    while(m != 0)
    {
        input = rand()%m;

        addNode(pHead, input);
        m--;

        // break if end of list
        if( input == -1)
        {
            break;   // end of list, don't add it to list
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("               %5.3f", time_spent);
}
```

It only prints out once so what's up with my stupid codes?!

Comment: What only prints out once?

Comment: The first value I enter. I expect it to print out the next 9 values with x++.

Comment: So it looks like your `while` loop never ends - run it in a debugger or add some prints to track what is happening.

Comment: Many possibilities,  Please show declaration of `n, begin, end,input, time_spent`.  Show value of `n`.  `input = rand()%n; ...  if( input == -1)` is never going to be true assuming `input` and `n` are `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statements aren't in the loops.

Therefore, they each only execute once.

Your print statements need to be in the loops if you want them to print each time the loop is run.

Also you need to initialize your 'n' variable to something greater than 0 if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution to this problem. Small mistake! Here is the solution.

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    n = 1000*x; //ta-da!!!!
    int m = n; //copy N value for new integer to do 2nd while loop
......
}
```

Hope this will be useful in the future to other programmers!